# In line If statement

Tags: java

bit of a newbie and trying to avoid a null pointer exception in a statement, so I want to set the value to an empty string. I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to be working, the value is still null.

```
row[2]==null? "" : row[2].toString()
```

Any help would be apreciated

Hi there, I tried with the 4 spaces, I am still left with a null value.

Comment: Are you setting that statement equal to anything? `String value = row[2]==null ? "" : row[2].toString();`

Comment: You may want to use [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-) instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: @BlueShrapnel OP does not have an NPE, OP wants to avoid `null` values.

Comment: @steve please show a bit more context in your code. It's not clear how you're using this expression, what the value of `row` is, etc.

Comment: please post a code that we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to *assign* a defaultValue to `row[2]` which can be achieved like below:

```
row[2] = row[2] == null ? defaultValue : row[2];
```

but a normal if would make more sense and be even clearer:

```
if(row[2] == null){
     row[2] = defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: while (iter.hasNext())

Comment: while (iter.hasNext())
{
 Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();
 vt = new TestObject(row[0].toString()
     row[1].toString(),
     row[2]==null ? "" : row[2].toString(),
     row[3].toString());
 pendingList.add(vt);
}

row 2 is null and I get an error when I try to save data. I want to set the value to blank so I do not get the null error.